# Nodejs function has inconsisten return points

Tags: node.js

```
Provider.prototype.configure = function(callback) {
var that = this;

if (that.getConfiguration() != undefined) {
    return callback(null);
}

models.configuration.all({where: {name: 'provider'}}, function (error, defaultProviderConfiguration) {
    if (error) {
        return callback(error);
    }
    that.setConfiguration(defaultProviderConfiguration[0]);
    return callback(null);
});
};
```

Please help me fix the inconsistent return points.

`Provider.getConfiguration()` is a sync method.

`Provider.setConfiguration()` is a sync method.

`models.configuration.all()` is an async method.

Comment: I'm confused ... this seems like it should work

Comment: inspectionJs from webStorm reported this.

Comment: The function sometimes sometimes calls the callback synchronously and sometimes asynchronously, which can cause hard to find bugs. See: ["Do Not Release Zalgo"](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony) by Isaac Z. Schlueter.

Comment: @Keloo reported what?

Comment: A rule I always follow with node.js is that once a function has a single asynchronous path, it must always be asynchronous.  This minimizes problems in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the problem is that you sometimes call the callback synchronously and sometimes asynchronously, you can just use `process.nextTick` to defer calling the callback until the next event loop tick:

```
if (that.getConfiguration() != undefined) {
    return process.nextTick(callback);
}
```

Although I'm not sure that's what your IDE is complaining about. Your IDE probably doesn't like how you "bail out early" with the return, which could be seen as a kind of spaghetti code. You could shut it up by rewriting the function like this:

```
if (that.getConfiguration() != undefined) {
    process.nextTick(callback);
} else {
    // rest of the function
}
```

For small functions like that, I'm not sure it's a big deal, though.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation for your IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/suppressing-inspections.html), you should be able to suppress that particular warning. Although I wouldn't get into the habit of doing this.